# Why doesn’t Swift call my overloaded method with a more specific type?

Tags: json, swift, overloading

I use [Decodable](https://github.com/Anviking/Decodable) to decode a simple struct from JSON. This works by conforming to a `Decodable` protocol:

```
extension BackendServerID: Decodable {

    static func decode(_ json: Any) throws -> BackendServerID {
        return try BackendServerID(
            id: json => "id",
            name: json => "name"
        )
    }
}
```

I’d like to be able to call `decode` with a `String`, though, so I have added an extension:

```
extension Decodable {

    static func decode(_ string: String) throws -> Self {
        let jsonData = string.data(using: .utf8)!
        let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
        return try decode(jsonObject)
    }
}
```

Then I would like to decode the objects like this:

```
XCTAssertNoThrow(try BackendServerID.decode("{\"id\": \"foo\", \"name\": \"bar\"}"))
```

This doesn’t work as expected, though, since somehow the `decode(Any)` method gets called instead of `decode(String)`. What am I doing wrong? (When I clarify the call by renaming my custom method to `decodeString`, it works correctly.)

Comment: how about renaming ```decode(_ string: String)``` to ```decode(string: String)``` and explicitly call ```BackendServerID.decode(string: "...")```?

Comment: Thank you! That would work, but I’d still rather have the type system figure out the argument type for me.

Comment: Consider using the [Swift3 naming conventions](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#weak-type-information), **precede each weakly typed parameter with a noun describing its role** like: `static func decode(string: String)`

Comment: I don’t want to get into a naming argument (honestly!), but in this case I think there is not much to clarify in the argument name – it’s obviously the thing to be decoded. See [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults) for a similar case. Neither of the `set` methods there prefixes the first argument name with its type.

Comment: Maybe you have misread the naming convention? Read its example again and compare it to UserDefaults. UserDefaults respects it and all its `set` methods a pretty much the same than the convention example.
There is no need for the `set` methods of UserDefault to precise the first argument label because a `Bool` cannot be resolved as a `String`. In your case, a `String` can be resolved to `Any`, then it is hard for the compiler to know call if he should call `decode(Any)` or `decode(String)` if you give him a `String` as first parameter.

Comment: I see! That makes sense, I’ll read it once more carefully. Thank you!

Comment: Could you create a minimal example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would agree that this behaviour is surprising, and you may well want to [file a bug over it](https://bugs.swift.org/).

From quickly looking through the source of [CSRanking.cpp](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/Sema/CSRanking.cpp), which is the part of type checker implementation that deals with the "rankings" for different declarations when it comes to overload resolution – we can see that in the implementation of:

> ```
> /// \brief Determine whether the first declaration is as "specialized" as
> /// the second declaration.
> ///
> /// "Specialized" is essentially a form of subtyping, defined below.
> static bool isDeclAsSpecializedAs(TypeChecker &tc, DeclContext *dc,
>                                   ValueDecl *decl1, ValueDecl *decl2) {
> ```

The type checker considers an overload in a concrete type to be more "specialised" than an overload in a protocol extension ([source](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/Sema/CSRanking.cpp#L520)):

> ```
>   // Members of protocol extensions have special overloading rules.
>   ProtocolDecl *inProtocolExtension1 = outerDC1
>                                          ->getAsProtocolExtensionContext();
>   ProtocolDecl *inProtocolExtension2 = outerDC2
>                                          ->getAsProtocolExtensionContext();
>   if (inProtocolExtension1 && inProtocolExtension2) {
>     // Both members are in protocol extensions.
>     // Determine whether the 'Self' type from the first protocol extension
>     // satisfies all of the requirements of the second protocol extension.
>     bool better1 = isProtocolExtensionAsSpecializedAs(tc, outerDC1, outerDC2);
>     bool better2 = isProtocolExtensionAsSpecializedAs(tc, outerDC2, outerDC1);
>     if (better1 != better2) {
>       return better1;
>     }
>   } else if (inProtocolExtension1 || inProtocolExtension2) {
>     // One member is in a protocol extension, the other is in a concrete type.
>     // Prefer the member in the concrete type.
>     return inProtocolExtension2;
>   }
> ```

And when performing overload resolution, the type checker will keep track of a "score" for each potential overload, picking the one with the highest. When a given overload is considered more "specialised" than another, its score will be incremented, therefore meaning that it will be favoured. There are other factors that can affect an overload's score, but `isDeclAsSpecializedAs` appears to be the deciding factor in this particular case.

So, if we consider a minimal example, similar to the one [@Sulthan gives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44260392/2976878):

```
protocol Decodable {
    static func decode(_ json: Any) throws -> Self
}

struct BackendServerID {}

extension Decodable {
    static func decode(_ string: String) throws -> Self {
        return try decode(string as Any)
    }
}

extension BackendServerID : Decodable {
    static func decode(_ json: Any) throws -> BackendServerID {
        return BackendServerID()
    }
}

let str = try BackendServerID.decode("foo")
```

When calling `BackendServerID.decode("foo")`, the overload in the concrete type `BackendServerID` is *preferred* to the overload in the protocol extension (the fact that the `BackendServerID` overload is in an extension of the concrete type doesn't make a difference here). In this case, this is regardless of whether one is more specialised when it comes to the function signature itself. The *location* matters more.

<sup>(Although the function signature *does* matter if generics are involved – see tangent below)</sup>

It's worth noting that in this case we can force Swift to use the overload we want by casting the method at the call:

```
let str = try (BackendServerID.decode as (String) throws -> BackendServerID)("foo")
```

This will now call the overload in the protocol extension.

If the overloads were both defined in `BackendServerID`:

```
extension BackendServerID : Decodable {
    static func decode(_ json: Any) throws -> BackendServerID {
        return BackendServerID()
    }

    static func decode(_ string: String) throws -> BackendServerID {
        return try decode(string as Any)
    }
}

let str = try BackendServerID.decode("foo")
```

The the above condition in the type checker implementation won't be triggered, as neither are in a protocol extension – therefore when it comes to overload resolution, the more "specialised" overload will be solely based on signatures. Therefore the `String` overload will be called for a `String` argument.

---

*(Slight tangent regarding generic overloads...)*

It's worth noting that there are (lots of) other rules in the type checker for whether one overload is considered more "specialised" than another. One of these is preferring non-generic overloads to generic overloads ([source](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/Sema/CSRanking.cpp#L495)):

> ```
>   // A non-generic declaration is more specialized than a generic declaration.
>   if (auto func1 = dyn_cast<AbstractFunctionDecl>(decl1)) {
>     auto func2 = cast<AbstractFunctionDecl>(decl2);
>     if (func1->isGeneric() != func2->isGeneric())
>       return func2->isGeneric();
>   }
> ```

This condition is implemented *higher up* than the protocol extension condition – therefore if you were to change the `decode(_:)` requirement in the protocol such that it used a generic placeholder:

```
protocol Decodable {
    static func decode<T>(_ json: T) throws -> Self
}

struct BackendServerID {}

extension Decodable {
    static func decode(_ string: String) throws -> Self {
        return try decode(string as Any)
    }
}

extension BackendServerID : Decodable {
    static func decode<T>(_ json: T) throws -> BackendServerID {
        return BackendServerID()
    }
}

let str = try BackendServerID.decode("foo")
```

The `String` overload will now be called instead of the generic one, despite being in a protocol extension.

---

So really, as you can see, there are *lots* of complicated factors that determine which overload to call. Really the best solution in this case, as others have already said, is to explicitly disambiguate the overloads by giving your `String` overload an argument label:

```
extension Decodable {
    static func decode(jsonString: String) throws -> Self {
        // ...
    }
}

// ...

let str = try BackendServerID.decode(jsonString: "{\"id\": \"foo\", \"name\": \"bar\"}")
```

Not only does this clear up the overload resolution, it also makes the API clearer. With just `decode("someString")`, it wasn't clear exactly what format the string should be in (XML? CSV?). Now it's perfectly clear that it expects a JSON string.

Comment: I am glad I was more or less correct. Very interesting idea about the cast of `BackendServerID.decode`. I couldn't find a syntax that would allow me to call the extension method directly.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the minimal example:

```
protocol Decodable {
    static func decode(_ json: Any) throws -> Self
}

struct BackendServerID {
}

extension Decodable {
    static func decode(_ string: String) throws -> Self {
        return try decode(string)
    }
}

extension BackendServerID : Decodable {
    static func decode(_ json: Any) throws -> BackendServerID {
        return BackendServerID()
    }
}
```

The implementation of `decode` in `BackendServerId` replaces the default implementation of `Decodable.decode` (the parameters are covariant, similar case as overriding). Your use case would work only if both functions were declared on the same level, e.g.:

```
extension BackendServerID : Decodable {
    static func decode(_ json: Any) throws -> BackendServerID {
        return BackendServerID()
    }

    static func decode(_ string: String) throws -> Self {
        return try decode(string as Any)
    }
}
```

Also note the `as Any` which is necessary to prevent recursion.

To prevent confusion, you should name functions that accept `string` and `Any` differently, e.g `decode(string:)` and `decode(json:)`.

Comment: I see! Thank you! How can I verify that my version replaces the default implementation?

Comment: @zoul I don't think you can. That's the problem with `static` functions, opposed to `class` functions. `class` methods would need an explicit `override` but `static` functions are just hiding their ancestor.

Comment: It doesn't "replace" the default implementation – `static func decode(_ string: String) throws -> Self` is *not* an implementation of the requirement `static func decode(_ json: Any) throws -> Self` in the first place. The requirement says that the method can accept *anything* as an argument, but the implementation says only strings. As far as I can tell, the compiler *should* just treat them as two separate overloads – therefore I think this is just a weird corner case with overload resolution.

Comment: @Hamish It's the other way around. The requirement says `String` and the implementation says `Any`.

Comment: The requirement, as listed in the protocol declaration, says `Any` @Sulthan.

Comment: @Sulthan In fact, you can remove the protocol requirement entirely, and just have it as a protocol extension method alongside the method in the conforming type – you still get the same behaviour, even though they should really just be treated as two overloads, so the `String` one should be dispatched to when calling with an argument type of `String`. This is further confirmed by the fact that if you replace the `Any` overload with one that uses a generic placeholder, i.e `static func decode<T>(_ json: T) throws -> BackendServerID`, it works as expected.

Comment: Although that being said, I am aware there are lots of rules when it comes to picking "the best" overload (concrete types are preferred over generic placeholders for one) – but I'd say the choice in this case is far from obvious and therefore I'd go so far as to say it's a bug.

Comment: @Hamish Would you mind adding your own answer? My answer is only a guess and I will be happy to delete it if you add a better one. This is definitely a complicated case.

Comment: I have [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44306189/2976878) @Sulthan :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should override `decode(Any)` or you can do something like that

```
extension Decodable {

    static func decode(String string: String) throws -> Self {
        let jsonData = string.data(using: .utf8)!
        let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
        return try decode(jsonObject)
    }
}
```

Here your define new method `decode(String string: String)` so `decode(Any)` method will not called.

Answer (score 0):

Swift is supposed to call the most specific implementation, you can try that in a playground to confirm; so your expectation is correct.

In your case, I suspect that the issue lies in access control levels.

In this `Decodable` library, method `func decode(_ json: Any)` is declared as `public`, thus it's available in your tests code.

On the other hand, your own method `func decode(_ string: String)` doesn't seem to be `public`, and then is `internal` by default, and not accessible in your tests code.

To fix that, either import your app's framework using `@testable` (which makes all internal symbols available), or declare the method `public`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are adding your functions to two different "things", the first function is added to `BackendServerID` and returns a `BackendServerID`, the second function is added to the `Decodable` protocol and returns a `Decodable`. The following will work in a Playground:

```
protocol Decodable {
    static func decode(_ json: Any)
}

extension Decodable {
    static func decode(_ json: String) {
        print("Hi, I am String-Json: ", json)
    }

    static func decode(_ json: Int8) {
        print("Hi, I am Int8-Json: ", json)
    }

    static func decode(_ json: Any) {
        print("Hi, I am Any-Json: ", "(I do not know how to print whatever you gave me)")
    }
}

extension Decodable {
    static func decode(_ json: Int) {
        print("Hi, I am Int-Json: ", json)
    }
}

class JSONParser : Decodable {
}

let five : Int8 = 5
JSONParser.decode(Int(five))
JSONParser.decode(five)
JSONParser.decode("five")
JSONParser.decode(5.0)
```

It will print

```
Hi, I am Int-Json:  5
Hi, I am Int8-Json:  5
Hi, I am String-Json:  five
Hi, I am Any-Json:  (I do not know how to print whatever you gave me)
```

and I think that should be what you expect.

However, your two static functions do not have *exactly* the same signatures and even if they have they are *not* considered to "overload" the same function. Paraphrasing @Sulthan slightly I tried

```
protocol Decodable {
    static func decode(_ json: Any) throws -> Self
}

struct BackendServerID {
}

extension Decodable {
    static func decode(_ string: String) throws -> BackendServerID {
        print("decoding as String: ", string)
        return BackendServerID()
    }
}

extension BackendServerID : Decodable {
    static func decode(_ json: Any) throws -> BackendServerID {
        print("decoding as Any: ", "(no idea what I can do with this)")
        return BackendServerID()
    }
}

try BackendServerID.decode("hello")
```

and I got

```
decoding as Any:  (no idea what I can do with this)
```

(as you would probably have expected by now). The `Decodable` function is "shadowed" and static functions are not accessible through their protocol type, but if I rename it as

```
extension Decodable {
    static func decodeS(_ string: String) throws -> BackendServerID {
        print("decoding as String: ", string)
        return BackendServerID()
    }
}
```

I can do

```
try BackendServerID.decode("hello")
try BackendServerID.decodeS("hello")
```

and get the expected result

```
decoding as Any:  (no idea what I can do with this)
decoding as String:  hello
```

On the other hand you can do

```
extension BackendServerID : Decodable {
    static func decode(_ json: Any) throws -> BackendServerID {
        print("decoding as Any: ", "(no idea what I can do with this)")
        return BackendServerID()
    }
}

extension BackendServerID {
    static func decode(_ string: String) throws -> BackendServerID {
        print("decoding as String: ", string)
        return BackendServerID()
    }
}

try BackendServerID.decode("hello")
try BackendServerID.decode(5)
```

and get

```
decoding as String:  hello
decoding as Any:  (no idea what I can do with this)
```

with an overloaded function (but it won't accept another `: Decodable` on the second `extension`). However, `extensions` of concrete types and of protocols do not mix which is very probably a *good thing* (TM).

Btw: I tried to coax it, but while

```
extension Decodable {
    static func decode(_ string: String) throws -> Self {
        print("decoding as String: ", string)
        return try BackendServerID.decode(string as Any) as! Self
    }
}

try BackendServerID.decode("hello")
try BackendServerID.decode(5)
```

would compile it only returned

```
decoding as Any:  (no idea what I can do with this)
decoding as Any:  (no idea what I can do with this)
```

since the `String` version on `Decodable` remained buried. But in any case it is nice to see how flexible Swift can switch on parameter types.

However you will probably be disappointed by

```
let five : Any = "five"
try BackendServerID.decode(five)
```

printing

```
decoding as Any:  (no idea what I can do with this)
```

so your whole dispatching is happening in a static way. If you are given an `Any` there seems to be no way to avoid `switch`ing on it to determine the dynamic type.