# inconsistent rules for operator overloading in swift

Tags: swift, recursion, operator-overloading

I'm seeing a strange difference in the way swift will overload `+` vs `>`:

```
protocol Value {
    func get() -> Float
    mutating func set(to:Float)
}
extension Float : Value {
    func get() -> Float {
        return self
    }
    mutating func set(to value:Float) {
        self = value
    }
}
func + (a:Value, b:Value) -> Float {
    return a.get() + b.get()
}
func > (a:Value, b:Value) -> Bool {
    return a.get() > b.get()
}

let a:Float = 1
let b:Float = 2
let c:Float = a + b //this works fine. Compiler calls Float + Float
let d = b > a //this causes infinite loop. Compiler recursively calls Value > Value
```

Any idea why the swift compiler is treating these cases differently?

Comment: Also is there a way to force call `Float > Float` in the higher level operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that the standard library currently has a `+` overload [defined directly](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/861ee3a11211369a78853c853a9e0145c0beff6a/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPointTypes.swift.gyb#L1597) on `Float`:

> ```
> //  TODO: These should not be necessary, since they're already provided by
> //  <T: FloatingPoint>, but in practice they are currently needed to
> //  disambiguate overloads.  We should find a way to remove them, either by
> //  tweaking the overload resolution rules, or by removing the other
> //  definitions in the standard lib, or both.
>
> extension ${Self} {
>   @_inlineable // FIXME(sil-serialize-all)
>   @_transparent
>   public static func + (lhs: ${Self}, rhs: ${Self}) -> ${Self} {
>     var lhs = lhs
>     lhs += rhs
>     return lhs
>   }
>
>   // [...]
> }
> ```

(where `${Self}` will be substituted by `Float`, `Double` & `Float80` upon gyb.py running)

When it comes to overload resolution, a `(Float, Float) -> Float` overload of `+` will win over a `(Value, Value) -> Float` overload when applied with `Float` operands, as the latter will require them to be converted from `Float` to `Value`.

However `Float` *doesn't* have a `>` overload defined directly on it; [it's instead defined as a top-level generic function](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/5109788c95310e5a4030e027ce8d34bc2144682f/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPoint.swift.gyb#L1505) over `FloatingPoint` operands:

> ```
> @_transparent
> public func > <T : FloatingPoint>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
>   return rhs.isLess(than: lhs)
> }
> ```

When it comes to overload resolution, your `(Value, Value) -> Bool` overload will win over this generic overload as overload resolution favours non-generic overloads (see the tangent [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44306189/2976878)). Therefore you'll wind up recurring. You could fix this by making your overload of `>` generic over `<T : Value>(T, T) -> Bool`, but then it would no longer be applicable to heterogenous `Value` operands.

Assuming you want the operators to be applicable to heterogenous operands, one foolproof solution would be to dispatch the calls to `>` and `+` via `Float`'s conformance to `Numeric` and `Comparable` by using nested generic functions. This can't recurse because neither
 `(Value, Value) -> Float` nor `(Value, Value) -> Bool` can satisfy the `+` and `>` requirements of these respective protocols.

```
func + (lhs: Value, rhs: Value) -> Float {
  func add<T : Numeric>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: T) -> T {
    return lhs + rhs
  }
  return add(lhs.get(), rhs.get())
}

func > (lhs: Value, rhs: Value) -> Bool { 
  func greaterThan<T : Comparable>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs > rhs
  }
  return greaterThan(lhs.get(), rhs.get())
}
```

(Note we're doing this for `+` as well as `>`, as the `+ (Float, Float) -> Float` overload may be removed in favour of a generic overload, which would cause the same problems as with `>`)

Another solution would be to avoid dispatching to `>` and `+` altogether, and instead just call the [`isLess(than:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float/1847350-isless) method on `Float` and the `+=` operator, mimicking the stdlib implementations:

```
func + (lhs: Value, rhs: Value) -> Float {
  var lhsFloat = lhs.get()
  lhsFloat += rhs.get()
  return lhsFloat
}

func > (lhs: Value, rhs: Value) -> Bool {   
  return rhs.get().isLess(than: lhs.get())
}
```

Though the calling of `+=` may be problematic if you implement an overload of it for `(inout Value, Value) -> Void`.