# Why is the Swift compiler marking this as an error?

Tags: swift, string, range, subscript, swift4.2

I have two ways of writing the same code, one of which seems to be disliked by the Swift compiler. Can you please explain why?

Context:

```
let guaranteedValue: String
let cursorPositionFromEnd: Int
```

Working code:

```
let stringFromEndUntilCursorPosition = String(guaranteedValue.reversed()[0..<cursorPositionFromEnd])
```

Non-working code:

```
let reversedOriginalString = guaranteedValue.reversed()
let stringFromEndUntilCursorPosition = String(reversedOriginalString[0..<cursorPositionFromEnd])
```

Compiler error message: "Cannot subscript a value of type `ReversedCollection<String>` with an index of type `Range<Int>`"

Other working attempt:

```
let reversedOriginalString = guaranteedValue.reversed()[0..< cursorPositionFromEnd]
let stringFromEndUntilCursorPosition = String(reversedOriginalString)
```

Basically the idea is you can only subscript a reversed range {but probably not only} if you add the index at a function return, but that does not work if you first reference the variable with a let or var and then try subscripting it.

I also understand that it would probably work in the "non-working code" if the Range would be String.Index type or whatever is the new fashion of doing it.

Can anyone explain why? Is this a bug in Swift's compiler which already has enough "twisted" string logic?

Comment: Interesting observation... To make things even 'stranger' if you do `let x = y.reversed` and then `let z = x()[0..<cursorPositionFromEnd]` doesn't work either... I would love to know why as well...

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/42688679: There are several `reversed()` methods. In your first example an array is returned, in the second example a “ReversedCollection” is returned.

Answer (score 6):

There are several `reversed()` methods, as explained in [What trouble could bring assining reversed() to a swift array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42688679/what-trouble-could-bring-assining-reversed-to-a-swift-array/42688868#42688868).

In your first code example,

```
let stringFromEndUntilCursorPosition = String(guaranteedValue.reversed()[0..<cursorPositionFromEnd])
```

the compiler infers from the context (i.e. the subscript) that the
[`Sequence.reversed()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/1641355-reversed) method is needed, which returns an array. Arrays are indexed by integers, 
therefore the code compiles. This method has `O(n)` complexity because a 
new array with all elements is created.

In

```
let reversedOriginalString = guaranteedValue.reversed()
```

there is no such context, and the compiler chooses the
[`Bidirectional.reversed()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/bidirectionalcollection/1782128-reversed) method. Compared to the above mentioned method, this one has
`O(1)` complexity. It returns a [`ReversedCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/reversedcollection) which 
has its own index type, therefore

```
let stringFromEndUntilCursorPosition = String(reversedOriginalString[0..<cursorPositionFromEnd])
```

produces the observed error message.

*Possible solutions:*

- Provide context to enforce the array creation:

  ```
  let reversedOriginalString: [Character] = guaranteedValue.reversed()
  // Or: let reversedOriginalString: Array = guaranteedValue.reversed()
  // Or: let reversedOriginalString = guaranteedValue.reversed() as Array
  let stringFromEndUntilCursorPosition = String(reversedOriginalString[0..<cursorPositionFromEnd])
  ```

  This works, but has the disadvantage of creating a temporary array.
- Do the proper index calculations on the reversed collection:

  ```
  let reversedOriginalString = guaranteedValue.reversed()
  let pos = reversedOriginalString.index(reversedOriginalString.startIndex, offsetBy: cursorPositionFromEnd)
  let stringFromEndUntilCursorPosition = String(reversedOriginalString[..<pos])
  ```

  This avoids the intermediate array, but is tedious to write.
- Use the `prefix(maxLength:)` method of sequences:

  ```
  let reversedOriginalString = guaranteedValue.reversed()
  let stringFromEndUntilCursorPosition = String(reversedOriginalString.prefix(cursorPositionFromEnd))
  ```

Comment: "the compiler chooses" sounds like a bug as the compiler is capable of reporting ambiguity in others cases, or am I missing something and its just a documented feature?

Comment: @CRD: As I understand it, the compiler chooses the most specific method, considering both the arguments and the context (the required return type). String is a BirectionalCollection (which is more specific than Sequence, but is not a RandomAccessCollection). Therefore BirectionalCollection.reversed() is chosen without more context. If the compiler sees that an Array should be returned, Sequence.reversed() is chosen. HTH :)

Comment: Choosing the "most specific" is the right thing to do if it is well-defined, and that's what I went looking for after I read your answer but failed to find a specification - which doesn't mean there isn't one I missed of course! Without a well-defined spec...

Comment: Further searching suggests that *most specific* might be "defined" in the compiler source (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801393/why-doesn-t-swift-call-my-overloaded-method-with-a-more-specific-type)). C++ source files are not the place to define language semantics :-(, especially when they contain comments like "this is a hack" :-( :-( One would hope that Apple knew better than this by now, maybe it is defined elsewhere...